# ASP.NET Core data protection in Framework (4.6) not working

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, machinekey

I have 2 old projects (vb.net) that use identity management which is part of an upgrade plan. However, due to time constraints, I need to part-release a new project in .net core also with identity management. These project need to work seemlessly together to persist users.

After some digging around I came across the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.SystemWeb` package which sounds like it should achieve what I need. I have set up the .net core app to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection` and I can see that a file is created with the keys etc in.

However, when I run this in the .net framework projects with the following MachineKey reference in web.config `<machineKey applicationName="MyAppName" compatibilityMode="Framework45" dataProtectorType="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.SystemWeb.CompatibilityDataProtector, Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.SystemWeb" />`, I get the following error:

> Could not create an instance of the configured DataProtector type.

I have searched for a solution to this but I haven't found any reference to this error. It seems like a basic configuration error as this error is displayed as soon as the site is launched, before I even get to login.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled the package and it seems to be running fine now...